# Comparing too many variables in if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, matrix, comparison

I wrote a code for my homework which says do inputs create a magic square matrix or don't. In magic square matrix, all of the rows, columns and diagonals sum must be equal. I wrote some functions to calculate the sum of the rows, columns and diagonals. At the end of the code I need to compare them to see they are equal or not. I assigned the results of the functions to different variables and I compared them in if statement at the end of the code. I am wondering is there any smarter way for comparison. I mean in my if statement there are too many variables and too many equality. I believe there is a smarter way for this.

```
package lab03;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class E7_15 {

public static boolean checkNumbers(int[][] array){
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
            if (array[i][j] < 1 || array[i][j] > 16){
                System.out.println("You entered a wrong value");
                return false;
            }
        }
        }
    return true;
}

public static int sumRow(int[][] array, int i){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<array[i].length; j++){
        sum += array[i][j];
    }
    return sum;
}

public static int sumColumn(int[][] array, int j){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<array[j].length; i++){
        sum += array[i][j];
    }
    return sum;
}

public static int diagonalSumRightToLeft(int[][] array){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        sum += array[i][array.length-1-i];
    }
    return sum;
}

public static int diagonalSumLeftToRight(int[][] array) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        sum += array[i][i];
    }
    return sum;
}

public static void main (String [] args){

    int[][] intArray = new int [4][4];
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        for ( int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            System.out.println("!!!Please enter your numbers between 1-16!!!");
            System.out.println("Enter your number for row " + (i+1) + " and column " + (j+1) + ": ");
            intArray[i][j] = in.nextInt();
        }
    }
    boolean done = checkNumbers(intArray);
    int sumLRD = diagonalSumLeftToRight(intArray);
    int sumRLD = diagonalSumRightToLeft(intArray);
    int r1 = sumRow(intArray, 0);
    int r2 = sumRow(intArray, 1);
    int r3 = sumRow(intArray, 2);
    int r4 = sumRow(intArray, 3);
    int c1 = sumColumn(intArray, 0);
    int c2 = sumColumn(intArray, 1);
    int c3 = sumColumn(intArray, 2);
    int c4 = sumColumn(intArray, 3);

    if (done == true){
        if(sumLRD==sumRLD && sumLRD==r1 && sumLRD==r2 && sumLRD==r3 && sumLRD==r4 &&
        sumLRD==c1 && sumLRD==c2 && sumLRD==c3 && sumLRD==c4 && sumRLD==r1 && sumRLD==r2 &&
        sumRLD==r3 && sumRLD==r4 && sumRLD==c1 && sumRLD==c2 && sumRLD==c3 &&
        sumRLD==c4 && r1==r2 && r1==r3 && r1==r4 && r1==c1 && r1==c2 && r1==c3 && r1==c4 &&
        r2==r3 && r2==r4 && r2==c1 && r2==c2 && r2==c3 && r2==c4 && r3==r4 && r3==c1 &&
        r3==c2 && r3==c3 && r3==c4 && r4==c1 && r4==c2 && r4==c3 && r4==c4 && c1==c2 &&
        c1==c3 && c1==c4 && c2==c3 && c2==c4 && c3==c4){
            System.out.println("This is a magic square matrix");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("This is NOT a magic square matrix");
        }
    }
    if (done == false){
        System.out.println("WRONG VALUE! START AGAIN!");
    }
    in.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to see if all those numbers are equal. Just use a loop that compares every variable in the list with the one following it:

```
public boolean allEqual(int... values) {
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length-1; i++) {
        if (values[i] != values[i+1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then replace your megacondition with:

```
if (allEqual(sumLRD, sumRLD, r1, r2, ...)) { 
    // ... 
}
```

This works because equality is *transitive* - i.e. if `a == b` and `b == c` then `a == c`. (The same for any number of variables.)

An alternative would be to refactor the whole check into something like:

```
boolean isMagicSquare(int[][] intArray) {
    // check diagonals
    int sum = diagonalSumLeftToRight(intArray);
    if (sum != diagonalSumRightToLeft(intArray)) {
        return false;
    }

    // check rows and columns
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (sum != sumRow(intArray, i) || sum != sumColumn(intArray, i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

// ...
if (isMagicSquare(intArray)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: To the OP: The `...` syntax in allEquals (known as varargs, or variable arguments) is probably the most concise way of checking equality for all of the numbers at once, but you may not have got to it in your studies yet. It automatically creates an array out of all of the arguments you pass. [This article from java.net](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/04/19/varargs.html) may provide some useful context.

Comment: I've also added an alternative take which uses the same approach, "unrolled" a bit, in a helper method to do the check.

Answer (score 0):

You could put all your sums in an array and use a function like this one in order to check if all the values are equal:

```
public static boolean allElementsTheSame(int[] array) {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        int first = array[0];
        for (int element : array) {
            if (element != first) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```